# Clustering Analysis on images

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a large set of scanned documents that I need to index however the the documents of interest are a small proportion of the entire package my classifier needs to identify. To get an idea of the optimum number of classes and how best to merge documents in a class I wanted to run an unsupervised clustering analysis.

Which distance method would work better to capture the structural information. Also would agglomerative  Hierarchical clustering be the best clustering approach for the given task? Thanks

Comment: Your question is confusing a lot of things. First you talk about images, then documents; first linear scans then classification, then clustering?!? First figure out *what* you want, then **attempt to solve the problem**, and show us where you are stuck. As is, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I am sorry about the confusion. Its basically the scanned images of documents that I need to eventually index. Because of the classifier closed set assumption for my project I have to include all the documents that might be in the package. However the documents of interest in that package which requires further validation are like 10 out of possible 100. So for the other classes I wanted to merge them as much as possible. For that I was considering if clustering could give me an idea which documents to merge. Again sorry I am a rookie and my approach might be wrong. Thanks

Comment: It is fundamentally different whether you analyze text images. Scanned docs probably need OCR first. Don't expect wonders from clustering. It can be a perfectly valid clustering result to have e.g. cluster with text written as "I" and a cluster using "We". Most likely the clusters are useless for your original objective, unless you carefully guide the process (or do classification).

Comment: Thank you for your insight I inevitably reached the same conclusion clustering didn't help at all. However classification I believe can work better. OCR presents its own set of challenges and inherently takes a longer time compared to classification which can work well if the documents have a distinct structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unsupervised clustering technique fails on scanned documents since it fails to grasp the underlying structure and ends up giving non nonsensical clusters. So the approach is fundamentally flawed. However Classification using deep convolutional neural networks, with sufficient data and carefully chosen distinct classes, can outperform OCR techniques if the documents have a distinct structure.

Comment: How would you apply classification without OCR first?

Comment: I am using Convolutional Neural Networks for classification